# Using Pandas groupby without a numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am using Pandas and have a dataframe with a date column, a unique ID column, and a dozen or so columns with numeric values. The following works well enough as a reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'day': ['2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01',
            '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02'],
    'distinct_id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'value': [71, 72, 73, 74, 74, 73, 72, 71, 71, 72, 73]
})
```

I would like to group by `day` and by `distinct_id` only, leaving out all the other columns. I just need to know that on a given `day`, a given `distinct_id` fired an event.

```
# Desired output
    day         distinct_id
0   2020-10-01  a
1   2020-10-01  b
2   2020-10-01  c
3   2020-10-02  a
4   2020-10-02  b
5   2020-10-02  c
```

If this were SQL, I'd write something similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT day, distinct_id FROM df
```

In Pandas, I can't figure out how to do it. The following is the groupby *object* that I think I want:

```
df.groupby(['day', 'distinct_id'])

# Output: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7ffd71bbd430>
```

However, all of the examples I can find for how to turn that into a dataframe involve a numeric aggregate of some kind. I could theoretically do this and then drop the resulting columns, like this...

```
df2 = df.groupby(['day', 'distinct_id']).count().reset_index()

# My actual example has a dozen or so columns to drop
cols = ['day', 'distinct_id']
df2.drop([x for x in df.columns if not x in cols], axis = 1)
```

...but that feels like a workaround. Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can select those columns and then `drop_duplicates`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'day': ['2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01',
            '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-02'],
    'distinct_id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'value': [71, 72, 73, 74, 74, 73, 72, 71, 71, 72, 73]
})

df[['day', 'distinct_id']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Nice! Go figure, I was too myopically focused on groupby. Thank you.